# Is there a way to retrieve the hypothetical growth of a stock from Yahoo Finance API?

Tags: python, yahoo-finance, yahoo-api

I'm interested pulling the hypothetical growth, including reinvested dividends, from the yahoo finance api. I wrote the following code that pulls the hypothetical growth in NOT including the dividends:

```
import yfinance as yf
data = yf.download("MSFT", '2015-01-01', '2021-09-10')['Adj Close']
ROI = (data[-1] - data[0]) / data[0]
print ("ROI:", ROI)
```

Is there data that factors in reinvested dividends available on their API somewhere, or do I need to go through the painstaking process of figuring out what the paid dividends were for each quarter, and factoring that in one quarter at a time inside a loop?

Answer (score 0):

First, Your phrase "hypothetical growth" is confusing since your using "AdjClose" data. This is not hypothetical.

Second, You're mistaken. Your understanding of what "AdjClose" represents is wrong. This value exists so that it does include changes to the stock such as dividends and stock splits.
For details refer to yahoo's knowledge base
[Yahoo's definition for Adj. Close](https://help.yahoo.com/kb/SLN28256.html)

However, if you're interested in comparing the changes(GROWTH) between Closing prices and "AdjClose", there is an easy math solution.

1. simply divide all Closing Prices by the first Closing Price in the series. This will give you the relative change and the normalized growth rate.
2. perform the same method to the "AdjClose" series. Now you'll see that these ratios are larger, which of course include the changes due to dividends and stock splits. These two ratios can now be directly compared.
3. If you wish to see the total changes in value, these are also simple calculations. But there are several results to consider and compute: a. simple stock price changes, b. accumulated prices + dividends without reinvestment, c. reinvesting accumulated prices + dividends + stock splits.

However providing you with specific code would require that you narrow your question.